# regex value is not matching jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to match clicked linked path with other links. It does not work at all.  Here's the code.
   I need to link's href starts with the regex.

```
 $('#taxonomylist ul li a').click(function() {
        $href = $(this).attr("href");
        $regex = new RegExp("^"+$href);
        $('#taxonomylist ul li').each(function() {
        $href_sub = $("a", this).attr("href");
        if ($href_sub.match($regex))
        {
        $(this).css("display", "block");
        }

       });
       return false;
        });
```

Here's what I got in firebug:

```
$href = "/?q=category/activity/test"  
$href_sub = "/?q=category/activity/test/lamp"  
$regex = /^\/?q=category\/activity\/test/
```

Everything seems find, but it does not work as expected. If I remove matching by regex, everything works fine (without filtering, of course).

EDIT:

Now it partially works, only assign css property to all links, not only those that match value. Does anyone see the problem?

```
$('#taxonomylist ul li a').click(function() {
$href = $(this).attr("href");
$regex = new RegExp("^"+$href);
$('#taxonomylist ul li').each(function() {
$href_sub = $("a", this).attr("href");
if ('$href_sub:contains($href)')
{
$(this).css("display", "block");
}

});
return false;
});
```

Comment: if all you're doing is matching the beginning of the value, regex is overkill. use `.indexOf` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[check this](http://jsfiddle.net/yNJKj/7/)

use `indexOf(//value to search)` for matching

hope it helps

Comment: it does not work. Still shows all things. Just does not run correctly. See: http://jsfiddle.net/yNJKj/4/

Comment: Thank you so much. It finally works! I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're asking if the regex **matches** your string. Meaning, your regex should at least look like this (based on your example):

```
$regex = /^\/?q=category\/activity\/test\/\w+/
```

You might want to use [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector instead.

Comment: Thanks! This solves problem partially. I cannot find an error. When I click a link, all other links are getting displayed, not only that are matched pattern. Do you see an error? Code is at the top of the page